# The norm of Fourier coefficients

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let's consider the space $\mathcal{R}$ of integrable functions with inner product given by:
$$<f,g> = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int \limits_{0}^{2 \pi} f(\theta) \overline{g(\theta)} \mbox{d} \theta$$
and norm $\left\lVert f \right\rVert$ by
$$\left\lVert f \right\rVert = <f, f> = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int \limits_{0}^{2 \pi} |f(\theta)|^2 \mbox{d} \theta.$$
I've defined a family
$$\{e_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} = e^{in \theta}.$$
It's easy to show that  the family above is orthogonal (even orthonormal in fact).
Now I define Fourier coefficients in a following way:
$$a_n = <f, e_n>.$$
It is written in my [book - Fourier Analysis An Introduction (Princeton Lectures)](http://prof.usb.ve/bueno/Libros/069111384X%20-%20Princeton%20University%20-%20Fourier%20Analysis~%20An%20Introduction%20-%20%282003%29.pdf) that
$$\left\lVert \sum_{|n| \le N} a_ne_n \right\rVert ^2 = \sum_{|n| \le N} |a_n|^2.$$
I'm afraid I can't see how it was obtained, because:
$$\left\lVert \sum_{|n| \le N} a_ne_n \right\rVert ^2 = \big< \sum_{|n| \le N} a_ne_n, \sum_{|n| \le N} a_ne_n \big> = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int \limits_{0}^{2 \pi} \big| \sum_{|n| \le N} a_ne_n \big |^2 \mbox{d} \theta \le \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int \limits_{0}^{2 \pi}  \big( \sum_{|n| \le N} \big| a_ne_n \big | \big) ^2 \mbox{d} \theta$$

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is a bad name for the set of integrable functions.

Comment: You went from $|\sum a_n e^n|^2$ to $\sum|a_ne_n|^2\quad\ddot\frown$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By bilinearity of the inner product,
$$\left\langle\sum_{|n| \le N} a_n e_n, \sum_{|m| \le N} a_m e_m\right\rangle
= \sum_{|n| \le N} \sum_{|m| \le N} a_n \overline{a_m} \langle{e_n, e_m \rangle}.$$
Now use the fact that the family $\{e_n\}$ is orthonormal.

Comment: Thanks! Of course. Then I will have $\sum_{|n| \le N} \sum_{m = n} a_n \overline{a_m} \langle{e_n, e_m \rangle}$ which gives what is needed.